# drush cc segmentation error when clearing theme-list

Tags: 7, drush, caching

I'm working on Vagrant/Virtual box and get a segmentation error when I `drush cc` theme list (8).

I'm new to Drupal and Vagrant and have no idea what this means. Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a problem with the Drush installation on my Vagrant box.